# avro::jsonEncoder and union

Tags: c++, avro

I have the following avro schema definition in `data_avro.json` file:

```
[
 {
     "namespace": "my.data",
     "type": "record",
     "name": "Data1",
     "fields" : [
         {"name": "i", "type": "int"}
     ]
 },
 {
     "namespace": "my.data",
     "type": "record",
     "name": "Data2",
     "fields" : [
         {"name": "u", "type": "double"},
         {"name": "val", "type": "int"}
     ]
 }
]
```

Now, i am trying to encode data like this :

```
avrodata::Data1 data1;
data1.i = 1;

avrodata::Data2 data2;
data2.val = 0;
data2.u = 2.5;

std::ifstream ifs("data_avro.json");
avro::ValidSchema schemas;

std::string err;

if (!avro::compileJsonSchema(ifs, schemas, err))
    std::cerr << "compileJsonSchema error : " << err << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "compileJsonSchema success" << std::endl;

auto encoder = avro::jsonEncoder(schemas);
auto out = avro::memoryOutputStream();
encoder->init(*out);

avro::encode(*encoder, data1); // avro::Exception is thrown here
```

but there is an error, output is :

```
compileJsonSchema success
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'avro::Exception'
  what():  Invalid operation. Expected: Int got Union
```

`avro::binaryEncoder` however seems to work fine instead of the `avro::jsonEncoder`.
How is it possible to encode this data using `avro::jsonEncoder` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Had any luck with solving the problem? I am currently staring at **basically** the same issue. Everything is the same, except I am getting an exception with `Invalid operation. Schema requires: Union, got: Int`.
I suppose this is because the schema begins with a union, but the type that I provide to `avro::encode` has a first field with `"field": "int"`.
Currently, I am trying to basically go for a **very** simple schema (without union and reused `"record"`s), which of course has its own problems and implications.

Comment: Also, I am trying with the `avro::jsonPrettyEncoder()`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments, I was/am facing the same (or at least a similar) problem as you. And even if this might not solve your problem, it should at least provide some clarity.

As I suspected, the problem lies with your `data_avro.json`. (Side note: It appears as if the convention was to use an `.avsc` file extention instead of `.json` for **av**ro **sc**hemas).

For the `jsonEncoder` to work, the schema(s) you use must not be surrounded with `[ ... ]`. More precisely, it appears that your schema must be a single `record` surrounded by a single pair of `{ ... }` at the top level.

I initially also had an `.avsc` with `[ ... ]` at the top level to be able to reuse `record`s and avoid copy paste errors... As soon as I just stupidly pasted all my records into a single, monstruous record, the `jsonPrettyEncoder` in my case worked fine.

For you, that means you need to split your schemas into 2 files, like so:

```
// Data1.avsc:
{
 "namespace": "my.data",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Data1",
 "fields" : [
     {"name": "i", "type": "int"}
 ]
}

// Data2.avsc:
{
 "namespace": "my.data",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Data2",
 "fields" : [
     {"name": "u", "type": "double"},
     {"name": "val", "type": "int"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: I am not working on that anymore but as far as i can remember that's exactly what i did (splitting the schema into multiple files) as a workaround.

Comment: Would you consider this enough of a warrant to accept my answer?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer just now.